# I can't show my toast message with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, text

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    signInButton(
      context,
      () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const HomeScreen(),
        ));
      },
      child: const Text("Toast Message"),
    ),
  ],
)
```

[Same Example in here](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast/example)
I made almost the same code as seen in the link. The only difference is that I defined the button as a separate widget and gave the values ​​inside the widget. But when I go to HomeScreen, I can't see the Toast message. Do I need to define this in the widget too?

```
Container signInButton(BuildContext context, Function onTap, {required Text child}) {
  return Container(
    width: 250,
    height: 50,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 20),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
    child: ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 221, 144, 56)),
      onPressed: () {
        onTap();
      },
      child: Text('Giriş Yap',
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          )),
    ),
  );
```

These are the codes of the widget I defined.

[image]

When I press the button, the application stops and shows this line of code.

Comment: The example on https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast/example does not actually show a toast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use use showtoast on press of the button

```
Container signInButton(BuildContext context, Function onTap, {required Text child}) {
  return Container(
    width: 250,
    height: 50,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 20),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
    child: ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 221, 144, 56)),
      onPressed: () {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "This is Center Short Toast",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
       );
      },
      child: Text('Giriş Yap',
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          )),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: A new error has occurred. I have attached the image of the error. What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Whats the error?